# Is it possible to create a dictionary "template"?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a recipe selector of sorts and am looking to create a unified dictionary template.  I currently have something like this:

```
menu_item_var = {'name': "Menu Item", 'ing': (ingredients)}
```

I'm concerned about retyping `name` and `ing` for every `menu_item_var`, for time's sake and the likely disaster of a mis-key.  I know I could add `Menu Item` as item 0 in my `tuple,` erase the `dict` and run a `for` loop to make the dictionaries safer, but that wouldn't convert the original `menu_item_var` from a `tuple` to `dict`.  Is there a "smarter" way of doing this?

Comment: how about simply doing {'menu_item': 'ingredients', ... } instead of having a 'name' and 'ing' as an additional processing step. would make your logic a little simple.

Comment: How about [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: or even just a tuple?  pairs of names and values are pretty common.

Comment: Actually the {'menu item': (ingredients)} isn't what I was thinking but it's really succinct and eliminates the majority of my problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd probably suggest looking at creating a class and using OOP instead for something like this.

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self,name,ingredients):
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients = ingredients
    def __str__(self):
        return "{name}: {ingredients}".format(name=self.name,ingredients=self.ingredients)

toast = Recipe("toast",("bread"))
sandwich = Recipe("sandwich",("bread","butter","ham","cheese","butter","bread"))
```

As your "template" get more and more complex, it becomes more than just a data definition and requires logic. Using a Class will allow you to encapsulate this.

For example, above our sandwich has 2 breads and 2 butters. We might want to keep track of this internally, like so:

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self,name,ingredients):
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients = {}
        for i in ingredients:
            self.addIngredient(i)
    def addIngredient(self, ingredient):
        count = self.ingredients.get(ingredient,0)
        self.ingredients[ingredient] = count + 1
    def __str__(self):
        out =  "{name}: \n".format(name=self.name)
        for ingredient in self.ingredients.keys():
            count = self.ingredients[ingredient]
            out += "\t{c} x {i}\n".format(c=count,i=ingredient)
        return out

sandwich = Recipe("sandwich",("bread","butter","ham","cheese","butter","bread"))
print str(sandwich)
```

Which gives us:

```
sandwich:
    2 x butter
    1 x cheese
    1 x ham
    2 x bread
```

Answer (score 7):

There are several very simple ways of doing this.  The simplest way that I can think of would be to just create a function to return that dictionary object.

```
def get_menu_item(item, ingredients):
    return {'name': item, 'ing': ingredients}
```

Just call it like this...

```
menu_item_var = get_menu_item("Menu Item", (ingredients))
```

**EDIT:** Edited to use consistent code styling, per PEP8.

Comment: It's better to be consistent with naming (camelCase/under_score). PEP8 suggests using lowercase+underscore. On a side note, welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Lol, thank you.  I typically use camelCase for everything (because I do a good bit of Java development), but also copied/pasted his variable.  But duly noted.

Comment: Quite simple and useful!

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use json and string interpolation to create a very basic dict template:

```
import json
template = '{"name": "Menu Item", "ing": %s }'

def render(value):
    return json.loads(template % json.dumps(value))

render([1,2,3])
>> {u'ing': [1, 2, 3], u'name': u'Menu Item'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to what [therearetwoosingoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673465/2084925) suggested,

```
>>> menu_item = lambda name, ing: {'name': name, 'ing': ing}
>>> sandwich = menu_item('sandwich', ['cheese', 'tomato'])
```

Now sandwich is:

```
>>> sandwich
{'name': 'sandwich', 'ing': ['cheese', 'tomato']}
```

Comment: This solution is indeed simple and straightforward. I just used it to do something similar and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are key-value mappings, generally used to have a flexible structure. Class instances are objects with a bunch of properties, generally used when you have a number of objects that all have a similar structure.

Your "dictionary template" really sounds more like a class (and all your dictionaries that need to fit this single template would be instances of the class), since you want these dictionaries not to be collections of an unknown set of key-value pairs, but to contain a particular standard set of values under known names.

`collections.namedtuple` is an extremely lightweight way of constructing and using exactly this kind of class (one whose instances are just objects with a particular set of fields). Example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MenuItem = namedtuple('MenuItem', ['name', 'ing'])
>>> thing = MenuItem("Pesto", ["Basil", "Olive oil", "Pine nuts", "Garlic"])
>>> print thing
MenuItem(name='Pesto', ing=['Basil', 'Olive oil', 'Pine nuts', 'Garlic'])
>>> thing.name
'Pesto'
>>> thing.ing
['Basil', 'Olive oil', 'Pine nuts', 'Garlic']
```

The "downside" is that they're still tuples, and so immutable. In my experience that's usually a good thing for small simple plain-data objects, but that might be a drawback for the usage you have in mind.

Comment: Actually the only issue I have with mutability is that each ingredient is a tuple of 3, an ingredient name, an equation to be altered by the guest count and a unit.  I initially had those tuples as lists so that the equation would change as guest count changed, but as far as I can tell I either have to establish guest count before my list-to-be-altered or somehow recall the variable.

Answer (score 2):

The fast and dirty way:

```
def menu_item(name, ing):
   return locals()
```

You get:

```
menu_item("toast", ("bread","butter"))
>>> {'name': 'toast', 'ing': ('bread', 'butter')}
```

Answer (score 0):

A python3 different flavour of OOP for reference.
subclass dict

```
class Recipe(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update({"name": "Menu Item"})
```

example usage

```
cake = Recipe(ing=('eggs', 'sugar', 'flour')
```