# Make dict into a json template

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a `dict` into a template (a schema?).

```
prod_item_template = {'prod_name': '',
                      'prod_quant': 0,
                      'prod_id': '',
                      'added_time': '',
                      '_template_version_': '0.0.1'}
```

`prod_item`s  will be saved to a `json` file later.

I've searched for answers and people suggest to use a `class` instead. However it won't work since items instantiating that class won't be able to serialized to json automatically.

I'm looking for best practice for this task so the answer doesn't have to be limited to `dict`.

Comment: What do you mean by "template"?

Comment: @martineau as an instance of a class / or a schema for a database? You can get some insights [here][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673376/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dictionary-template-in-python] but the problem with that answer is it doesn't work for `json` serialization.

Comment: In that case, you could make it a class and use (the first part, with a `to_json()` method) of my answer to the question [**_Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder).